# selected python interpreter is not written in user/workspace setting in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter, user-preferences

I use VSC latest version (1.59) on mac/osx. When i modify some settings usually they should be recorded in the user setting. If i open my setting in json format , some lines will look like this :

```
"workbench.settings.editor": "json",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai",
"workbench.iconTheme": "ayu",
```

That's the changes i made to the color theme and file icon. But when i change my python interpreter in the command palette -> python:select interpreter, the changes i made is not recorded/written there. I expect line like :

```
python.defaultInterpreterPath = .....
```

But i doesn't exist. It actually behaves properly and use the selected python interpreter as expected but it's just not being written to the user setting.json file inside my user directory (/Users/andi/Library/Application Support/Code/User/setting.json) or inside the .vscode folder in current project.

Does anyone know where this setting has been written to ?

Answer (score 0):

It will modify the setting of `python.pythonPath` instead of `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in your Workspace setting.

The explanation of `python.defaultInterpreterPath`([official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_general-settings)):

> Path to the default Python interpreter to be used by the Python
> extension on the first time it loads for a workspace, or the path to a
> folder containing the Python interpreter. Can use variables like
> ${workspaceFolder} and ${workspaceFolder}/.venv. Using a path to a
> folder allows anyone working with a project to create an environment
> in the .venv folder as appropriate to their operating system, rather
> than having to specify an exact platform-dependent path. settings.json
> file can then be included in a source code repository. Note: **Changes**
> **to this setting made after an interpreter has been selected for a**
> **workspace will not be applied or considered by the Python extension.**
> **As well, the Python extension doesn't automatically add or change this**
> **setting.**

**Update:**

Sorry for that. For testing, I have used the Python Extension with an older version. `python.pythonPath` can not be changed in the new version.

`python.defaultInterpreterPath` only work for the first time, and will not be changed when you switch the python interpreter([official docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments)).

> A new optional setting python.defaultInterpreterPath is introduced in
> the user and workspace scope, from which the extension **will read the**
> **value when loading a project for the first time.**
>
> **Changes to the**
> **python.defaultInterpreterPath will not be picked up by the Python**
> **extension once an interpreter is already selected for the workspace.**
> **The extension will also not set nor change the value of this setting,**
> **it will only read from it.**

In fact, the `python interpreter` path will be stored in the local storage
and you can not modify it.

Comment: Yes, python.pythonPath is just the first thing i'm looking for. But it's just doesn't exist anywhere both in my user setting and workspace setting. I don't use venv. So normally it's suppose to be under .vscode folder in current workspace or in my user lib folder.

Comment: And because the python.pythonPath doesn't exist and i got some warning said that the pythonPath is obsolete when trying to manually add it, so i then look for python.defaultInterpreterPath

Comment: @andio thanks for your response, could have a look at the update of this answer?

Comment: @andio Does this help? If you have any doubt about it, feel free to let me know.